# the following error after installing crystal report for vsts 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, conflict

Ihat should i do, i just installed crystal reports for vs2010

now this error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Web\10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Web.dll' and 'c:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Web\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Web.dll'

Source Error:

Line 80:      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button_Test_Test" OnClick="working" />
Line 81:    
Line 82:         <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" ReportSourceID="CrystalReport1.rpt" />
Line 83:    
Line 84:     </asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Open your web.config file and make sure all the references that mention Crystal Report are 13.0.2000.0. There will be several in the Assemblies section (12 or 13 I think). Next open the page where you have the Report Viewer and make sure you are registering the same version as you have in the web.config

<%@ Register assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, ....

I have not had your exact error before but I have several errors similar and editing these two files to make sure all the versions line up has worked for me every time.